# TypeScript keyof returning specific type

Tags: typescript, types

If I have the following type

```
interface Foo {
    bar: string;
    baz: number;
    qux: string;
}
```

can I use `typeof` to type a parameter such that it only takes keys of `Foo` that return `string` (`'bar'` or `'qux'`)?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

### Typescript 4.1 and above

With the addition of the `as` clause in mapped types we can now simplify the original type to:

```
type KeyOfType<T, V> = keyof {
    [P in keyof T as T[P] extends V? P: never]: any
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRyARnFAFzIDOYUoA5gNwHGlwBeVIArgLYloLQsQCOPAB5Va9EMwIBfAgTABPAA4oA0hFXUA8jAAqGiAB4jAGmQA1AHzIAvMgDWu9DBytiAbQAKyKCu7p5GyHDUyEb+ALrIEBKQIAAmkTYA-Mh+3BAAbtAxVHAgqorK+AA2EGDI6CAVqgDKdIzUVDp6hiaaZhjo1jKMdsJ1Dc2yDJHOAORkHNPIAPSL8VBQ6FAEo00tclPIs+QLy7Uu5VU12wBy-IJQbcgdBsamvZjWvALQw1v1qjdfe5OA5zY4rdBnfDXW7QfaHKBg1brKDIIA)

### Original answer

You can use conditional types in Tyepscript 2.8 :

```
type KeysOfType<T, TProp> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends TProp? P : never }[keyof T];

let onlyStrings: KeysOfType<Foo, string>;
onlyStrings = 'baz' // error
onlyStrings = 'bar' // ok

let onlyNumbers: KeysOfType<Foo, number>;
onlyNumbers = 'baz' // ok
onlyNumbers = 'bar' // error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRyARnFAFzIDOYUoA5gNwHGlwBeVIArgLYloLQsQCOPAB5Va9EMwIBfAgTABPAA4oA0hFXUA8jAAqGiAB4jAGmRGAClHTqAfMgC8OZAG1byUMgDWuugwNgC6VEbeocgQEpAgACbUNvaOAPzIPtwQAG7QyAqegarBYcIEADYQYMjoIBWqAMp0jNRUOnqGJppmGOjWMoxOwnUNzbIMye4A5GQc08gA9IsxUA5QBKNNLXJTyLPkC8u1-sr4VTVbAHL8glBtyB0Gxqa9mNa8AtDDm-WqN197m59nMjit0Kd8NdbtA9gcoGDVutkEA)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. in my using it, I found I needed to extend `KeysOfType` to include `keyof T & { [P ....` or else I couldn't use a `KeysOfType` to then subscript `T`.

Comment: How to make it to respect nullable column like `number | null` filtering properties which have `number` type?

Comment: [Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) to docs of 'as' clause.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for - now I was able to write:
`type TypeSafeUnion<T1, T2> = { [P in keyof (T1 | T2) as T1[P] extends T2[P] ? T2[P] extends T1[P] ? P : never : never]: (T1[P] | T2[P]); };`

Comment: With it I can get *only* the compatible keys of two type as simply
`keyof TypeSafeUnion<Foo, Bar>`. Meaning I can write a Pick type that lets you pick only compatible properties that exists in _both_ of two types, meaning I can write type safe patch methods between dto/model objects that have no type relation between them. :)

Comment: (Technically you could do this before too, but the compile error if you picked a mutual but non-type-matched key would be on one of the objects instead of on the key, which has subpar clarity.)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, I was wondering the same... it seems we can do something like ``` type KeyOfTypeOptionalIncluded<T, Condition> = KeyOfType<T, Condition | undefined>``` for optional keys or even ``` type KeyOfTypeNullIncluded<T, Condition> = KeyOfType<T, Condition | null>``` for the example you mentioned.... or even  ``` type KeyOfTypeNullIablencluded<T, Condition> = KeyOfType<T, Condition | null | undefined>``` for optional nullable types

Comment: @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir, I think you should update your answer enhancing the `KeyOfType` so that it works with functions as @Robby Cornelissen answered my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74272393/how-to-distinguish-different-functions-signature-with-conditional-type-checks

Comment: Doesn't work for generic types - indexing the object with keys like these does not result in a type compatible with `number`.