# Constrain keys using value type

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript function a bit like this:

```
function lookup<Object, Key extends keyof Object>(object: Object, key: Key): any
```

Now, can I constrain the key type using the type of the produced value? Example:

```
interface Animal {
    name: string;
    legs: number;
}
```

Now can I constrain `lookup` to only allow keys that have a `string` value? Ie. that calling `lookup(animal, "name")` would be valid, but `lookup(animal, "legs")` would be not.

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit more?

Comment: maybe duplicated to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49752151/typescript-keyof-returning-specific-type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some play with generics and conditional types might do the trick

```
type KeysOfType<T, P> = { [K in keyof T]: P extends T[K] ? K : never }[keyof T]

function lookup<T, K extends KeysOfType<T, string>>(object: T, key: K): T[K] {
    return object[key];
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=8&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2QbwChkTkQ5MIAuZAZzClAHMBuY0nCJ2mkAV0wAjaG1LIwATwAO1Og2ajStAPaUAQsuWc4IGoM3aQhAL6FCkmcgDSECbQDyMACrSIAHicAaZAAUAfMgAvATIANpWyKDIANa2yjDITgC6ND7IEAAekCAAJrSJ4UnIAPzWyLwQAG7QyMahsRLxiUlmMHwgCGDAyiDIOJrRfFIe3hGZ2XnWtg7OriNyjCBMfn4AFMqCAFYQnTReMbY0VgCUe4UE7CRQEGB8UL0b2531tklspoQIPfTIcDToWFwQQuYnIlBoAHJaBDPJc%20lweMgAEywsQWWQQwQwuEqdQGCA6GjwHC0CBmD5fEA-OAAOQoKGC-WUgykqzg3ghYIgEOObEp1JclkZAyGbI56J5bAA9FLkAABMC0AC0mRknRVUCgyign2%20YF%20ABkEcCmSyxcgIZxuJLCDL5YqVRk1WANVqdfz9XAAMqqCAaLQE3rC5mi9kW3F%20-E6G12hXK1U7F3QN26qn69rREDKADuIBsEhNItZYc5yjAAEkQE4ABbQbm8oA)

Comment: Very interesting!

Comment: This allows Object types

Comment: @MuratKaragöz Yep, something more restrictive `type KeysOfType<T, P> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends P ? P extends T[K] ? K : never : never }[keyof T]` would work I guess.

Comment: Yours works well. But you could make it shorter by using `lookup<Object, Key extends keyof Object>(object: Object, key: Key extends string ? Key: never)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following

```
function lookup<Object, Key extends keyof Object>(object: Object, key: Object[Key] extends string ? Key: never)
```