# KeysOfType and exact type of property

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using KeysOfType from https://stackoverflow.com/a/49752227:

`type KeysOfType<T, TProp> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends TProp? P : never }[keyof T];`

With these interfaces

```
interface SomeInterface {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}

interface AnotherInterface {
  a: number;
  b: string;
  c: number;
  d: string;
}

interface DataInterface {
  someProp: SomeInterface;
  anotherProp: AnotherInterface;
  ...
}
```

If I use it like showed below, I get error

**Type 'SomeInterface' is not assignable to type 'SomeInterface  & AnotherInterface '.

Type 'SomeInterface ' is missing the following properties from type 'AnotherInterface ': c, d**

```
  const setProperty = (numberValue: number, stringValue: string, propName: KeysOfType<DataInterface, SomeInterface>) => {
    const obj: SomeInterface = {
        a: numberValue,
        b: stringValue
    };

    data[propName] = obj; // data is DataInterface
  }
```

How can I get property keys of DataInterface that are exactly have type of SomeInterface?

Comment: Could You please share reproducable example of `setProperty`. I just dont know where did you get `data` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that at the moment of the assignation, `propName` is of type `"someProp" | "anotherProp"`.

Typescript does a simple thing :

- Can I put `obj` inside of `data.someProp` ? Yes
- Can I put `obj` inside of `data.anotherProp` ? No -> Error

---

To show you that this is true, look at the following playground : [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Having the following code works :

```
  if (propName === 'someProp') {
    data[propName] = obj;
  }
```