# Make typescript parameter keyof K and typeof FormGroup

Tags: angular, typescript, types, typeof, keyof

I want to pass in an object which is key of a class K and has the type of or extends FormGroup like:

```
  public async myMethod<T, K>(
    ...
    formGroupName: keyof K & typeof FormGroup) { }
```

So wenn I call it then, the keyof K seems to work as I only get K members, but also others, i just want to receive from type of FormGroup!

This would be the function call:

```
this.service.myMethod<ComponentA, ComponentB>(
  ...
  'form' // any member of ComponentB, which is of type formGroup
);
```

Thank you

Comment: `keyof` produces a string or numeric literal union. How can this intersect with `FormGroup`? Can you add an example of how you want to call `myMethod`

Comment: i would like to receive only properties of type FormGroup. 
i would then pass formGroupname: 'form'

Comment: Can you please add a complete function call to the question, as an example

Comment: added an implementation

Comment: Ok, now it's clear :) Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49752151/typescript-keyof-returning-specific-type