# Typescript error after updating @types/jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I recently updated the `@types/jest` package in my project from version **24.9.1** to version **29.4.0**. However, I'm now encountering a parsing error in the index.d.ts file of the package itself, located in the `node_modules/@types/jest` directory. The error message is `Parsing error: ']' expected`.

[image]

I'm not sure if this issue is caused by my TypeScript version, which is 3.8.3, because when I tried the same update on a different project with the same TypeScript version, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following type definition is broken in your version (3.8.3), because this new `keyof`-`as` syntax was introduced in TypeScript 4.1.

```
type Func = Function;
type NonFunctionPropertyNames<T> = keyof { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends Func ? never : K]: T[K] };
```

> See: [*"TypeScript keyof returning specific type"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49752227/1762224)

You will need to upgrade your TypeScript compiler to a version ≥ 4.1.

### Test cases

Broken in version `3.8.3`

> https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.8.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMZQLy0U4BLA9ggbgChRIoA5feZHfABQCddIHRyBDAWwgGcAeACoA+NFADWEELgBmUAN5QA2gGko2BOMkyoAqOx46VAXSgQAHsAgIAJgeooA-FAQQAbhAZQAXFGVGfAsZQAL4EQA

Works in version `≥ 4.1`

> https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMZQLy0U4BLA9ggbgChRIoA5feZHfABQCddIHRyBDAWwgGcAeACoA+NFADWEELgBmUAN5QA2gGko2BOMkyoAqOx46VAXSgQAHsAgIAJgeooA-FAQQAbhAZQAXFGVGfAsZQAL4EQA